# Did signed_data JSON change in V3 from those in V2?

Tags: android, json, in-app-billing

Our API receives `signed_data` JSON made during a purchase and parse it. We made this API while in-app billing was in V2.

I switched library to V3 and send the `signed_data` to the API , but it reports error.

Sadly, we did not save any V2 JSON of `signed_data` and cannot do cross compare. And we cannot query V2 in-app billing API any more.

Does anyone know if this JSON changed in V3 of in-app billing? I cannot find any piece of information about this on Google official pages. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got both JSON from another sources. For anyone in the same troubles as myself, here they are both JSONs.

```
V2 signed_data
    {
       "nonce":-1234,
       "orders":[
          {
             "notificationId":"1234",
             "orderId":"1234.5678",
             "packageName":"com.xxx.yyy",
             "productId":"mysku_1",
             "purchaseTime":1111111,
             "purchaseState":0,
             "purchaseToken":"abcdefg"
          }
       ]
    }
```

and here is another one

```
V3 signed_data
    {
       "orderId":"1234.5678",
       "packageName":"com.xxx.yyy",
       "productId":"mysku_1",
       "purchaseTime":12334,
       "purchaseState":0,
       "purchaseToken":"TOKEN_STRING"
    }
```